# Cannot connect via SSH, misconfiguration

Tags: 14.04, sshd

I've been messing around with `sshd_config` and tried to add a script to run on login. Unfortunately, when I now attempt to login with SSH I receive `bash: /etc/update-motd.d/99-custom-text: Permission denied`. Is there anyway I can fix this? I do not have physical access to the server as it's hosted on DigitalOcean.

Comment: Does `ssh -t machinename bash` work?

Comment: I still get the same response from the server. `bash: /etc/update-motd.d/99-custom-text: Permission denied`.

Comment: Try giving permissions to the ssh users using chmod to read /etc/update-motd.d/99-custom-text

Comment: The only solution was for me to reset the root password via the DigitalOcean dashboard and use the console on their site.